# Potential for Accessibility and Assistive Technology Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've spent a little over a decade working in accessibility and assistive technology, helping people with disabilities use computers by providing specialist software, hardware and training.

There are various forums and mailing lists online that I use when I need support in my work. They're of varying quality, and there is no central point of reference (as far as I know) for discussion and Q and A's relating to accessibility and assistive technology.

What do you all think of Stack Exchange hosting a Q and A site to cover these topics?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about creating a new Stack Exchange site. Please use http://area51.stackexchance.com to follow or create new site proposals instead.

Comment: I would encourage you to propose a new site on Area 51 if you'd like. This sounds like an important topic and one that expert answers are sorely needed in. *But*, in the meantime, I think that some questions would be on-topic for existing sites. Accessibility as it concerns application *developers* is perfectly on topic for Stack Overflow. Accessibility as it concerns *end users* is perfectly on topic for Super User. Etc.

Comment: Proposal created at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58367/assistive-technology?referrer=87VGGd3kGwVJj1f1VHuVwA2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a suggestion on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) - that's where site suggestions are born and come to fruition (though not all survive the process).

There are currently [Web Accessibility](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45059/web-accessibility), [Impaired Living](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57545/impaired-living) and [Blindness](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/56773/blindness) proposals that you can support, though they all appear to be subsets/supersets of what you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks, I've created a proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58367/assistive-technology?referrer=87VGGd3kGwVJj1f1VHuVwA2